# How is RNN decoder output calculated?

Tags: neural-network, rnn, encoder

I was trying to read [RNN Encoder Decoder paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1078).

#### RNN (plain RNN i.e. non encoder-decoder RNN)

It starts with giving equation for RNN:

- hidden state in RNN is given as:

  [image: List item]  ... equation (1)

  where f is a non linear activation function.
- The output is a softmax:
  [image] ... equation(2)
  for all possible symbols j = 1, ..., K.

#### RNN encoder-decoder

Then it explains RNN encoder-decoder:

- The RNN encoder decoder architecture is given as follows:
  [image]
- There are two equations for encoder:

  - The encoder hidden state equation is same as that for plain RNN, i.e. equation (1)
  - The summary of the whole input sequence, which is indicated by letter c is nothing but the hidden state produced after reading last input word. (c for "context" as that forms input context for decoder):
    [image]
- The decoder hidden state is calculated as follows:
  [image]
  This is indicated by circles in decoder in above image each of which takes y_(t-1), c and h_(t-1) as input.

What I am not able to get is how y_t is calculated in decoder? Is it by using softmax as in equation(2). If yes exactly how? Note that diagram shows three inputs for calculating y_t: h_t, c and y_(t-1). How these inputs are incorporated for calculating y. The paper does not seem to discuss this, or am I misreading?

**Update**

I just found that paper says:

[image]

for an activation function g which must produce valid probabilities, e.g. a softmax. But still its unclear how exactly these three (h_t, y_(t-1) and c) variables can be included in softmax.

Answer (score 0):

The paper's Appendix A has the exact formulas used. Specifically A.1 contains the exact formula for calculating $\mathbf{c}$, and  A.1.1 contains details on where and how it is used.

Comment: Ohkay I missed that. [This](https://i.postimg.cc/630zSSbF/image.png) is how it defines y. I might take some time to get the intuition behind that. But the immediate doubt is that I dont find g_j (smaller g) defined anywhere. Is it the jth component G (larger G) defined at the end?

Comment: Oof, that's a pretty big omission... I've been out of the MT field for a few years now, my guess would be that g and s relate to the output language model that is integrated into the translation system.

Comment: I guess $g$ refers to single row of $G$, a standard practice: refer individual row / column with small letters and whole matrix with capital letters.

Comment: Right, that would make $g_j$ the $K \times 1$ embedding vector for the $j$th output type, which  makes sense in the context.